# iOS Swift CoreBluetooth CBL2CAPChannel L2CAP Channel Oriented Connection Cannot Reconnect After Close From Central

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am working with iOS (swift) attempting to create an L2CAP Connection Oriented Channel between two devices, one central and one peripheral.

I have successfully got both to connect and communicate. My question is that once I have connected and have a valid stream, if that stream is closed/disconnected, I cannot seem to re-open the L2CAP channel.

What I am doing is the following:

1. Establishing the connection initially (which works fine).
2. Then I unpublish the channel on the peripheral side.
3. This causes the stream .endEncountered event to fire on the Central.
4. In this event handler I call to cleanup the channel/stream.
5. Republish the channel on the peripheral side.
6. Attempt to connect to channel again but it fails.

Oddly, If I close the  BLE connection, delete the CentralManager and Peripheral object (on the central side), and reestablish the connection and objects from scratch, it will connect to the same peripheral just fine. This leads me to believe that the peripheral side is operating just fine, but that something is not being cleaned up on the central side correctly before I attempt to reestablish my connection.

*Note: I would like to be able to keep the BLE connection alive and just re-establish the L2CAP connection when the L2CAP channel is re-published by the peripheral (which causes the didModifyService to be called, which kicks off the whole process of reconnection)*

Am I missing something in the cleanup? Is there any demo code that shows an L2CAP channel being closed and then re-opened? The only question I found related to this was never answered and taken down by the OP.

Thanks for any help offered!

The following is the relevant CB delegates:

**Central's Characteristic Update:**

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?){
    if let dataValue = characteristic.value {
        let psm = dataValue.uint16
        self.peripheral?.openL2CAPChannel(psm)
    }
}
```

**Centrals Open Channel:**

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didOpen channel: CBL2CAPChannel?, error: Error?)
{
    self.channel = channel
    self.channel?.inputStream.delegate = self
    self.channel?.outputStream.delegate = self
    self.channel?.inputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: .default)
    self.channel?.outputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: .default)
    self.channel?.inputStream.open()
    self.channel?.outputStream.open()
}
```

**Stream Delegate:**

```
public func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event)
{
    switch eventCode
    {
    case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
        print("Stream Event .openCompleted: \(aStream) is open")
    case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
        print("Stream Event .endEncountered")
        self.cleaUpL2CAP()
    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        print("Stream Event .hasBytesAvailable")
    case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
        print("Stream Event .hasSpaceAvailable")
    case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
        print("Stream Event .errorOccurred")
    default:
        print("Unknown stream event")
    }
}
```

**L2CAP Cleanup Code**

```
private func cleaUpL2CAP()
{
    print("Closing Streams")
    self.channel?.inputStream.close()
    self.channel?.outputStream.close()
    
    self.channel?.inputStream.remove(from: .main, forMode: .default)
    self.channel?.outputStream.remove(from: .main, forMode: .default)
    
    self.channel?.inputStream.delegate = nil
    self.channel?.outputStream.delegate = nil
    
    self.channel = nil
}
```

The following is the output I get in my log:

```
Channel opened: <CBL2CAPChannel: 0x283b327f0 peer = <CBPeripheral: 0x28068a120, identifier = 49FCD310-5028-4ED3-74EE-385713E8608B, name = iPhone X, state = connected>, psm = 192>
2021-08-12 00:01:18.312949-0500 POC[22913:6701893] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
Stream Event .openCompleted: <__NSCFInputStream: 0x2805f5b00> is open
Stream Event .hasBytesAvailable
Stream Event .openCompleted: <__NSCFOutputStream: 0x2805f7cc0> is open
Stream Event .hasSpaceAvailable
Stream Event .endEncountered
```

Comment: I have updated my [L2CapDemo](https://github.com/paulw11/L2CapDemo) and [L2Cap library](https://github.com/paulw11/L2Cap) so that you can open and close the stream independent of the BLE service advertisement.  It is now working for me

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: I took a long look at your updated code. My code is based on your original demo and l2cap package, thank your for providing it for the community :) . When I compare what I have done it is almost identical to what was added in your recent update. The only difference I can find is that in the connection.close() of your code the entire connection object is deleted along with all its members. It seems there is some other cleanup being performed that I am missing. Do you have knowledge or ideas of any object or things that need to be deleted/cleaned before a connection can be reestablished?

Comment: The main change I made was to publish a `nil` PSM when the channel is removed so that the central can also clean up its side of the channel and close the streams. When the channel is republished the PSM attribute is also updated.

Comment: Thanks, I did miss the change with the nil PSM and update to the characteristic. I fixed this and found another issue where on the peripheral side I was accidentally creating multiple instances of the characteristic. These fixed my issue and I am now able to disconnect and reconnect successfully. Thanks again for your demo app and your help!